# How to restrict my iphone app to run only when SIM is there

Tags: ios, swift, iphone

When SIM is removed from iphone, the user should be presented with a popup to insert SIM and app should not work until SIM is there.

Option 1:
I tried below solution to check if phone is able to send msgs there by detecting SIM is there or not,

```
let isCapableToSMS: Bool
        if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(NSURL(string: "sms:")! as URL) {
                isCapableToSMS = true
            } else {
                isCapableToSMS = false
            }
        if (!isCapableToSMS || !isCapableToCall) {
            print ("#######No SIM\n")
        } else {
            print ("##### SIM\n")
        }
```

Option 2:

I also tried adding notification observer for SIM removal, **CTRadioAccessTechnologyDidChange** but this seems to be deprecated.

Option 3:
Also tried below solution,

```
let isCapableToCall: Bool
        if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(NSURL(string: "tel://")! as URL) {
            isCapableToCall = true
        } else {
            isCapableToCall = false
        }
```

But this is also not working.

Comment: This api is deprecated without replacement. [this thread](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/714876) in the Apple developer forums has some discussion.

Answer (score 0):

try this method to check whether the device has SIM or not and show you a pop-up according to true/false status.

```
func hasSim() -> Bool {
    let network = CTTelephonyNetworkInfo()
    guard let info = network.serviceSubscriberCellularProviders?.filter({ $0.value.carrierName != nil }).first?.value else {return false}
    return info.isoCountryCode != nil ? false : true
}
```

Comment: I am getting warning like "subscriberCellularProvider" is deprecated in iOS 12.0, is there any other way.

Comment: 'serviceSubscriberCellularProviders' was deprecated in iOS 16.0: Deprecated with no replacement, also 'carrierName' was deprecated in iOS 16.0: Deprecated; returns '--' at some point in the future